# How to keep VS2015 NuGet from adding packages to TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget, visual-studio-2015

VS2013 had a bug where NuGet would add packages as pending changes, even if you told it not to with `.tfignore`. There was a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28868519/145173), but it doesn't work with VS2015/NuGet3, and NuGet is back to its old tricks. Is there a "Nu" workaround? :-)

Microsoft Connect item: [NuGet adds packages to TFS despite .tfignore](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1640242)

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but after smashing my head against the TFS wall for a couple years, I convinced my team that git was the way to go... `.gitignore` actually works like you'd expect :-)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It looks like this is fixed in [version 3.2 RC](http://blog.nuget.org/20150902/nuget-3.2RC.html) of the NuGet Visual Studio 2015 Extension - updating to this version worked for me, at least.

A discussion about this issue can be found [here](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/980) where it is recommended to update from NuGet 3.1 to 3.2 RC.

**Update**

Version 3.2 of the extension has now been released (found [here](https://dist.nuget.org/visualstudio-2015-vsix/v3.2.0/NuGet.Tools.vsix)) which includes this fix.

**Clarification**

To get this working you need two things:

1. A `nuget.config` file containing the `disableSourceControlIntegration` setting
2. A version of the NuGet Visual Studio 2015 Extension that respects the `disableSourceControlIntegration` setting (versions from 3.2 onward should work)

As indicated in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/he-il/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#how-settings-are-applied):

> NuGet first loads NuGet.config from the default location, then loads any file named NuGet.config starting from the root of the current drive and ending in the current directory.

This means that you can specify `<solution><add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" /></solution>` in the [default config file](https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior#config-file-locations-and-uses) for your user profile (found at `%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config`) or in the NuGet config file in your solution directory, e.g., `\MySolution\.NuGet\NuGet.config`.

Comment: I've found it easiest to add the `disableSourceControlIntegration` option to the default config file at `%APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` like so:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
</configuration>`

Comment: @dsghi You've just solved something for me that has been annoying me since 2013. I never knew there was a GLOBAL nuget.config file!

Comment: I'm on 3.2 RC and still get the error. It may be worth noting that this project was created in 2013 and migration to 2015

Comment: @dougajmcdonald Keep in mind that simply updating the extension probably won't solve this problem if it already exists (i.e., the packages folder is in source control already). In that case you'll need to remove the packages folder from TFS before VS will start ignoring it.

Comment: I just did a new project with VS2015.  Using 3.3.0.167 of NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio.  Upon `Add Solution to Source Control` it added the packages folder, subfolder, binaries, etc.  I don't think this answer works.

Comment: @RickGlos Did your new project have a nuget.config file? You'll still need one so that you can set the `disableSourceControlIntegration` setting.

Comment: @dsghi Cheers, I've incorporated that into my answer. Can you remember which version of the NuGet extension you were using back then? Version 3.1 broke support for `disableSourceControlIntegration`.

Comment: @nick_w  File -> New Console App and then `Install SomeNugetPackage`  - does not add a NuGet.config file to the solution or project folder so I went with the advice below using `%AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.Config`.  I did not know about this extra file you could optionally create for the solution itself.

Comment: This worked well, but didn't realize at first that it's per user, since APPDATA is a user profile. So I think this has to be copied to each programmer, on any machine they use.

Comment: Still an issue with VS 2015 Upd3 Nuget 3.5, packages are checked in and I have no \MySolution\.NuGet\NuGet.config

Comment: @Mikee Unless I am misunderstanding you, the lack of the nuget.config file (and hence the `disableSourceControlIntegration` directive) is why the packages are being checked in.

Comment: @nick_w Am I wrong in thinking that by default now  VS2015\NuGet should be configured to not check in packages? ....it's been quite sometime since I created a new solution under source control.

Comment: @Mikee I don't believe that a NuGet.config file is added to the solution by default, meaning that packages are getting checked in. If you want to you could disable the package checkin at your user profile level so that it gets applied to any solution. Like you, I am surprised that a more sensible default has not yet been arrived at given how undesirable it is to check packages in.

Answer (score 5):

In your `%AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.Config` file, add the following just before the `</configuration>` XML tag...

```
<config>
  <add key="repositoryPath" value="C:\NuGetPackages" />
</config>
<solution>
  <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
</solution>
```

...you can specify any path you want - the important thing is putting it OUTSIDE your TFS workspace!

Now you never have to worry about that stuff again. Your solution folder will not contain any packages anymore; all solutions will default to using your custom packages location instead.

NOTE - This works is on a per-user basis.

*Until now, I've been doing the same in a one-config-per-solution (`\.nuget\NuGet.Config`) manner. Thanks to @dsghi for the insight!*

*Make sure your solution folder does not contain a `.nuget` folder (old way of doing things). Even if the folder is NOT included in the solution and only in the file system, it will override everything!*

Comment: This worked but you really have 2 answers going on here.  I only want to `disableSourceControlIntegration` not also pick a new location for the `repositoryPath`.

Comment: The reason this works is most likely because you have updated your version of the NuGet VS 2015 Extension. In version 3.1 the `disableSourceControlIntegration` setting didn't work no matter where your config file was.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I've been doing this since VS2013

Comment: Me too. What I mean is that 3.1 broke support for that setting - it worked fine before and after that.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I haven't found a real solution yet.

The only workaround I've found so far is:

- Right click the packages folder in "Team Explorer - Pending Changes"
  and select "undo".

Comment: The workaround really just step 1. "Undo pending changes" doesn't delete files, and you don't have to check in right away. While, it's good that there is a reasonable workaround, perhaps is presence is also the curse that has kept this bug from getting any love for so long.

Comment: Yeah you are correct. I was overthinking the problem.