# Where did Microsoft Connect for Visual Studio 2015 go?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

It used to be that if you wanted to submit a bug for Visual Studio 2015, you'd go to the Visual Studio area on Microsoft Connect and choose Visual Studio 2015 from the [feedback center](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/LoadSubmitFeedbackForm). However, VS2015 is no longer in the list. Furthermore, links to previously reported VS2015 bugs no longer work ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31887010/145173)).

Where did the bug reporting for VS2015 go?

Comment: It now redirects [to this page](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).  Probably has something to do with the overwhelming amount of feedback :)

Comment: I had a VS 2015 bug report that disappeared, reappeared and now has disappeared again. At least some links to VS 2015 bug reports still work, so it's not entirely clear what's going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was a transient bug. VS2015 shows up in the feedback center again, and the example linked in the question now works.