# all library references missing in one C# project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution with 3 C# projects built in VS2013. It was checked out from GIT but I got all library references missing (marked as yellow triangle) in one project.

But, the same lib references are all ok in the other two projects.

I have tried all solutions in [All system references missing Visual Studio 2013 NuGet Async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208012/all-system-references-missing-visual-studio-2013-nuget-async)

but, none of them work for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
This is part of the c# project file, why they are missing in this project but not in other projects ?

```
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
<Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
<Reference Include="System.Core" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.SQLite">
```

I have project 1,2,3 in one solution.

In the same solution, project 1 can find the same lib reference from a local path.

But, when I added the same lib reference from the **same** local path to project 2, it **cannot** find it.

Why ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your `.csproj` file. It defines where the referenced DLLs are located.  Obviously you don't have the folder/files that are required.

Comment: I have project 1,2,3 in one solution.

In the same solution, project 1 can find the same lib reference from a local path.

But, when I added the same lib reference from the same local path to project 2, it cannot find it.

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem today. After all the headache I finally found out that I need to move the package folder from the mother project into the new project. It's the missing packages that caused all the headache.

In your case, I suspect in your project2 package folder, System.Data.SQLite package is missing.